# Fgets reading empty line and adding them into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, fgets

I have problem I'm reading a file with `fgets()` like that:

```
FILE *input;
char line[256];

input = fopen("test.txt","r");

while((fgets(line,255,input)) != NULL) {
    //printf("%s",line);
        add(line);
}
```

Then function add is inputing lines into linked list. It's working but when I have file like:

```
hello
dog

cat
```

It's inputing empty line too..
Any idea how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: add `if (*line == '\n') continue;` before `add(line);` Remember `fgets` *reads and includes* the trailing `'\n'` ending each line. If all you read was the `'\n'`, then you read an empty line -- skip adding it.

Comment: You can also simply do `if (*line != '\n') add (line);` to eliminate the `continue;` `:)`

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it =)

Comment: Just make sure you understand `*line` is just shorthand for `line[0]` (e.g. a pointer holds the *address of* the first element in any array (or string), dereferencing the pointer returns *the contents* of the first element). If your first character in `line` is a `'\n'`, that is a blank (or empty) line.